# Windows VPN Server How to Use Multiple Public IP Addresses

Tags: windows, vpn

I have set up Windows VPN Server to my server. It has several public ip addresses such as 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.1.3, 1.1.1.4 but when client connects to VPN it only gets 1.1.1.1 as public IP. What I need is to get random public IPs when connecting to internet. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple `--remote` directive for adding multiple server.

for random you should use the `--remote-random` directive